# FOR command variable expansion errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a program that gets the file size for a specific file (don't worry about the `if` statement or the `LINE_NUMBER` variable)...

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %Q in (%currentRoom%) do set Nfilesize=%~zQ
if Nfilesize GTR filesize (
    set /A "LINE_NUMBER=LINE_NUMBER + 1"
)
endlocal
```

(P.S. `%currentRoom%` is a file called `bob.txt`)

I keep getting this error after I test it (using the `CALL` command)...

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~zX
```

Can you help me? (I'm kind of new to the `FOR` command)

Comment: Please replace the screenshot with a text representation of the error. The Windows command prompt supports copying contents through the system menu.

Comment: %nfilesize% %filesize%. I would suggest you post the entire batch file instead of this small section of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a batch file you have to use `%%Q` and `%%~zQ` as help of command **FOR** displayed on running in a command prompt window either `help for` or `for /?` explains.

Also you forgot `%` around the environment variable names on **IF** condition.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filesize=16384"
set "currentRoom=myroom.txt"
for %%Q in (%currentRoom%) do set "Nfilesize=%~zQ"
if %Nfilesize% GTR %filesize% (
    set /A "LINE_NUMBER+=1"
)
endlocal
```

You need to use delayed expansion by using `!` instead of `%` if the **FOR** loop and the **IF** condition are within a block defined with `(` ... `)` for all variables which are modified within the block like variable `Nfilesize` in example below.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filesize=16384"
set "currentRoom=myroom.txt"
(
    for %%Q in (%currentRoom%) do set "Nfilesize=%~zQ"
    if !Nfilesize! GTR %filesize% (
        set /A "LINE_NUMBER+=1"
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing a batch script, use `%%` for `for` loop variables.

```
for %%Q in (%currentRoom%) do set Nfilesize=%%~zQ
```

Comment: @andersamer - then you have left something out of your question, because the code as you have currently described it works perfectly. http://i.imgur.com/lBSShJs.png

Comment: Would any code before matter? (e.g. other `for` loops)

Comment: @andersamer - Seeing as how the error is mentioning `%~nX` and we're only using `Q`, I expect the code that is using the `X` variable to be causing that particular error. Based on _literally every other time this has been asked on the internet_, it is 100% because you're missing a `%` somewhere in a `for` loop variable. It wouldn't hurt to edit your question to include the entire code you are working with.